# Stop systemd service from running at boot

Tags: boot, systemd, services

I don't want my systemd service to run at boot and I can't stop it.

I created my own script, service and timer files for automatic back ups to Backblaze. I've found 3 or 4 forum posts on the matter, but none of those solutions helped me.

If I remove the `[Install]` section in the .service the status changes to `static`. And it still runs at boot.

Here is my .service file:

```
ryley@pop-os:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/b2backup.service 
[Unit]
Description=Backblaze Backup Script

[Service]
User=ryley
Group=ryley
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ryley/b2backup.sh --full --to-external
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is my timer file:

```
ryley@pop-os:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/b2backup.timer
[Unit]
Description=timer for Backblaze upload script
Requires=b2backup.service

[Timer]
Unit=b2backup.service
OnCalendar=Sun 03:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the status:

```
ryley@pop-os:~$ systemctl status b2backup.service 
● b2backup.service - Backblaze Backup Script
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/b2backup.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2020-11-23 20:58:30 PST; 12h ago
TriggeredBy: ● b2backup.timer
    Process: 944 ExecStart=/home/ryley/b2backup.sh --full --to-external (code=exited, status>
   Main PID: 944 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

This shows the service is disabled:

```
ryley@pop-os:~$ systemctl list-unit-files --state=disabled
UNIT FILE                              STATE    VENDOR PRESET
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount          disabled enabled      
acpid.service                          disabled enabled      
b2backup.service                       disabled enabled
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been at this for several hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your `/etc/systemd/system/b2backup.timer` file.

Specifically, this line:

```
Requires=b2backup.service
```

From the [systemd.timer documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html):

> For each timer file, a matching unit file must exist, describing the unit to activate when the timer elapses. By default, a service by the same name as the timer (except for the suffix) is activated. Example: a timer file foo.timer activates a matching service foo.service. The unit to activate may be controlled by Unit= (see below).

- `foo.timer` will always trigger `foo.service`. Systemd automatically matches the name ('foo')
- To specify a different service file(s) use `Unit=someOtherService` (different from the `[Unit]` section)

Unfortunately, a `Requires=` line creates a *dependency*. Systemd must run the dependency *before* it can start the service or timer.

- A `Requires=foo` line tells systemd to run that service *before* starting the timer.

Simply delete the `Requires=` line from your timer. You don't need it (systemd already knows which service the timer triggers), and it's causing the behavior that you don't want.

Comment: Yep. I commented out the "Requires=" line and rebooted. The script did not run. I have every confidence it will run at the scheduled time. Thanks again!!!